# Image Slider using Range Slider and Dot Controls

Tags: javascript, slider

I am modifying w3schools basic image slideshow carousel to work with a range slider as well as clickable dots. The goal is to be able to move the slider, and the image changes. I'm not concerned with styling as much, as long as I can understand the concept or logic that needs to take place. I would imagine the clicked "dot value" matches the "slider value" somehow. Advice?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  var RangeValue = document.getElementById("myRange").value;


  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

}
```

```css
.slide-container {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
  right: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

.slide-container h1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgb(53, 53, 53);
}

#run {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: #95A56E;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgb(53, 53, 53);
}

.slide-container img {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgb(53, 53, 53);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #95A56E;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.range-slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.range-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #95A56E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #95A56E;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgb(53, 53, 53);
}

.range-slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <h1>Featured Cases</h1>
  <h1 id="run">Run This Design</h1>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/GWRevision – 1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/Web 1920 – 1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="images/Web 1920 – 1.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="2" class="range-slider" id="myRange" oninput="currentSlide()">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own!

Added a onclick to the range slider and set it to the currentslide function like the dots above , except equal to the rangeslider's value.

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value = "1" class="range-slider" id="myRange" onclick="currentSlide(value)" >
```

Added this to end of javascript, after *dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";*

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("myRange").value = slideIndex;
```

very basic stuff I'm sure but I just wanted to learn. Now if I drag the slider or click the dots, it goes to the correct image.